# What is DNS TXT record "mailru-verification"?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, authentication, spam-filter

Sometimes I see this `mailru-verification` DNS record.

I've Googled *- and Yandexed ;) -* but I found nothing about it.

I suspected that is a kind of russian SPF implementation...

```sh
dig example.com TXT
```

outputs

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu <<>> example.com TXT
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56090
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.    IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com. 14400 IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:xxxxxx.xx -all"
example.com. 14400 IN  TXT "mailru-verification: xxxxxxxxx"
example.com. 14400 IN  TXT "spf2.0/pra include:xxxxxxx.xx -all"

;; Query time: 78 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 02 12:36:52 CEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 210
```

Does someone know something about it?
Thanks!

Comment: Apparently mail.ru has a statistics/problem notification service that a domain's postmaster can sign up for: https://postmaster.mail.ru I assume they will require you to verify your ownership of a domain by adding a `mailru-verification` header provided by them to your DNS zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's domain verification for service [PostMaster.mail.ru](https://postmaster.mail.ru/).
There you can get some statistics about your letters delivery, spam, problems, configure feedback loop and so on. 
Quite handsome.

If you have big audience with @mail.ru addresses you may find it useful for you. It has an interface in English too.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's used for domain ownership verification when signing up for some SaaS-style service where you're allowed to use your own domain name.

This is fairly common practice to thwart abuse, and in such cases no one but that service provider is expected to actually make use of the record.

Presumably this one is for some service provided by *mail.ru*, based on the *mailru* bit in the value.

Answer (score 1):

TXT records are kind of a description for the entry. One can write whatever he wants in these entries. This is mostly for internal use and does not affect the ip/name resolution.

See also: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXT_record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXT_record)

Comment: TXT records are also used for mail autentication sandard protocols (SPF, SenderID, DKIM, DMARC)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, but even the official Amazon SES (Simple Email Service) domain `amazonses.com` has `mailru-verification` and also `google-site-verification` DNS TXT records which are used to verify site ownership (and get email delivery statistics from Mail.ru and Gmail):

```
nslookup -type=TXT amazonses.com
amazonses.com   text = "mailru-verification: 71ab435de908d6ed"
amazonses.com   text = "google-site-verification=aOJq8aXEtCO23r176f6iOTGt-RVuPv81XPtBuIzRTx0"
amazonses.com   text = "v=spf1 ip4:199.255.192.0/22 ip4:199.127.232.0/22 ... -all"
```